# Taken long execution time if Dax function In power BI

Tags: powerbi

Problem it's taken very long time in execution.any one suggest how we  can improve execution time.
It's taken around 165548 ms.
Multiple if statements.
Like if final score > =1 then result "competency level very bad"
Same if statements repeat till final score >= 10.

Comment: Can you show the example code, we can't help without it. You may me able to use SWITCH rather than IFs

Comment: There are some ways to improve  IF statements, but you should share your code so we can help you.

Comment: grade new = 
IF([Final Score]<6,"Competency      Level    Below Avg",
IF([Final Score]>=6 && [Final Score]<7,"Competency      Level    Average",
IF([Final Score]>=7 && [Final Score]<8,"Competency      Level    Good",
IF([Final Score]>=8 && [Final Score]<9,"Competency      Level    Very Good",
IF([Final Score]>=9 && [Final Score]<10,"Competency      Level    Excellent",
IF([Final Score]=10,"Competency      Level    Outstanding"))))))